# Validating start and end time scenarios using moment.js when midnight and other times

Tags: javascript, validation, momentjs

Within my app I have two fields: `Start Time` and `End Time`. Both these fields use a time-picker that allows the user to enter the following 24 hour format `00:00:00` (HH:MI:SS).

Using moment.js, I need to check for the following scenarios:

1. `Start Date` and `End Date` times cannot be the same unless the user has entered:

`Start Time: 00:00:00` and `End Time: 00:00:00` - **which is VALID**

where as:

`Start Time: 01:00:05` and `End Time: 01:00:05` - **which is INVALID**

2. Keeping scenario 1 in mind, `End Time` cannot be before `Start Time`

Example cases:

```
Start Time: 00:00:00
End Time  : 00:00:00

=> VALID

Start Time: 00:00:04
End Time  : 00:00:03

=> INVALID - end time prior to start time

Start Time: 18:10:32
End Time  : 18:10:32

=> INVALID - start and times here cannot be the same. Only if midnight (00:00:00) for each
```

Being new to moment.js, I have seen functions like `isSame` but unsure how to put it all together to achieve above scenarios, specifically for times alone as the examples I've seen, involve whole dates.

I have tried the following and not sure if the best way to cover all  my scenarios as I hoping to have the results returned to be booleans.

At the moment I am getting the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: startTime.isSame is not a function`

Code is:

```
let startTime = moment('07/08/2021 01:00:05').format('HH:mm:ss');
let endTime = moment('08/08/2021 01:00:05').format('HH:mm:ss');

if (startTime !== "00:00:00" && endTime !== "00:00:00") {
  console.log(startTime, endTime)
  if (startTime.isSame(endTime)) {
    console.log("cannot be same");
  } else if (endTime.isBefore(startTime)) {
    console.log("End time cannot be before start time");
  }
} else {
  console.log("same....");
}
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

After dispensing with the zero check, it's just a question of whether one date `isBefore()` another.

```js
function hasZeroTime(m) {
  return m.hours() === 0 && m.minutes() === 0 && m.seconds() === 0;
}

function valid(startTime, endTime) {
  if (hasZeroTime(startTime) && hasZeroTime(endTime)) return true;
  return startTime.isBefore(endTime);
}

let startTime = moment('07/08/2021 01:00:05', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
let endTime = moment('08/08/2021 01:00:05', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss');

console.log(`well-ordered times should succeed...${valid(startTime, endTime)}`);

console.log(`both times equal and non-zero should fail...${valid(startTime, startTime)}`);

// swap the order
let tempTime = endTime;
endTime = startTime;
startTime = tempTime;

console.log(`incorrectly ordered times should fail...${valid(startTime, endTime)}`);

startTime = moment('07/08/2021 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
endTime = moment('07/08/2021 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss');

console.log(`two zero times should succeed...${valid(startTime, endTime)}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```